# Show that nowhere dense set under homeomorphism is nowhere dense

Tags: general-topology

Given homeomorphism $f: X \to Y$ and nowhere dense set $B \subset X$ show that $f(B)$ is nowhere dense set in $Y$.

I know that:

- $f$ is homeomorphism $\implies$ $\left(U \text{ open in } X \iff f(U) \text{ open in } Y \right) (\star$)
- homeomorphism preserves density ($\star \star$)

I tried using above two to prove it but it seems a little sketchy:

$$
B \text{ is nowhere dense in } X \implies \\ B^\complement \text{ is open and dense in } X \implies \\ f(B^\complement) \text{ is open and dense in } Y \text{ (using } \star \text { and } \star\star ) \implies \\ f(B) \text{ is nowhere dense in Y } $$

Comment: @YuiToCheng is it really the proof? It seemed too simple for me so I expected a flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: Notice a nowhere dense set needs not to be closed, e.g. $\{1/n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$. See Henno Brandsma's answer for the correct definition.

Comment: Your equivalence of nowhere dense is wrong: you need the complement of the *closure* of $B$ to be open and dense.

Comment: Use that $f[\overline{A}]=\overline{f[A]}$ and likewise for interior for all subsets $A$ of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism and $B \subseteq X$ is nowhere dense then $f[B]$ is nowhere dense too:

$B$ is nowhere dense iff $\operatorname{int}(\overline{B}) = \emptyset$

Homeomorphisms preserve interiors and closures so

$\operatorname{int}(\overline{f[B]}) = \emptyset$ too and hence $f[B]$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: $\operatorname{int}(\overline{f[B]}) = \operatorname{int}(f[\overline{B}])$ comes from another homeomorphism definition equivalence. How exactly did you conclude that $\operatorname{int}(\overline{B}) = \emptyset \implies \operatorname{int}(\overline{f[B]}) = \emptyset$ though?

Comment: @Tomasz $f[\emptyset]=\emptyset$; apply $f$ to both sides of the definition of nowhere denseness of $B$ and apply the facts about interior, closures and $f$-images.

Comment: Thank you very much!